# Describe all of the homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_{20}$ to $\Bbb Z_{40}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm starting abstract algebra and I'm having difficulty understanding how to find homomorphism. For instance, I want to find all homomorphisms of $$ \varphi (\Bbb Z_{20}) =\Bbb Z_{40}.$$
I know that the GDC of both groups gives me the number of existing homomorphisms. But I don't know how to proceed and find them all. I know that I'm supposed to take 1 as it is the generator of the group. Could you help me understand how to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: $\varphi$ must take $0$ to $0$ (since only the identity is the element of a group that acts as an identity when added to all possible elements).  What options are there for $\varphi(1)$?  Now, since $2 = 1+1$, do you have any freedom to choose $\varphi(2)$, or must $\varphi(2) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(1)$?  Same question for the elements $3, \dots, 19$ in $\Bbb{Z}/20\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is generated by 1, so consider the possible values of $f(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the homomorphism as $\varphi$, and $\varphi(1)=x$. Then, $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by $x$.(Why?)

Moreover, $20x=\varphi(20)=\varphi(0)=0$. So, $x$ must be order 20 or its divisor. $x$ can be $0,2,\cdots,38$. So there are 20 homomorphisms(When $x$ is even, then $20x\equiv0\bmod40$).

Then, $\forall n\in\mathbb Z_{20}$, $\varphi(n)=n\varphi(1)=nx.$ (of course, $x=0,2,\cdots,38$.)

**Edit**

$\varphi$ is additive group homomorphism, so $\varphi(n)=\varphi(1+\cdots+1)=\varphi(1)+\cdots+\varphi(1)=n\varphi(1)$.

Comment: ()=(1) is it because n = n * 1? So, () * (1) =  (1) = 

Comment: @TheMathAI No, because $n=1+1+\cdots+1$(n times), and $\varphi$ is additive group homomorphism.

Comment: Why can you take out the n from () and say ()=(1)?

Comment: @TheMathAI See last part of my answer. If you use the advanced concept, this is clear, because **additive group** is $\mathbb Z$-**module**.

Comment: Now I understand it, thank you! @Nightflight

Comment: Last question, could we have defined x differently to include 39 for instance?

Comment: Order of x must be 20 or lower, but order of 39 is not 20 or lower(it is 40). So $x\ne39$, for example.

Comment: "$x$ *can* be $0,2,\dots,38$": how do you know that *every* one does actually give rise to a homomorphism?